# Left navigation folds in even if current?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a left navigation with an animation on a hover - You can see it here:
http://www.wearewebstars.dk/frontend/test/boerneunivers2.html

If you ex: click the second navigation item, then that "li" get a class: current - But when leaving the "li" item, then it collapses - Is does that because of some javascript, but it shouldnt do that os the "current" LI. 
In the script my Hover function should only be triggered if the LI is not the current one - See my script here:

```
$(".left-navigation ul li:not(.current)").hover(function( e ){

     var mEnt = e.type=="mouseenter"; // boolean true/false
     //alert(mEnt);

     $(this).stop().animate({width: mEnt?'95%':35}, mEnt?100:0, function() {
         $(this).find("span.nav-text").css({
             display: mEnt? "inline-block" : "none"
         });
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should look like this:

```
$(".left-navigation ul li:not('.current')")
```

I think this is self-explanatory ;)

EDIT: Try doing it with this:

```
$(".left-navigation ul li:not(.current)").hover(function(){
    //mouseenter
},function(){
    //mouseout
});
```

Comment: Still collapses to the 35px on the current <li>

Comment: I belive there is a problem with using .hover() the way you did.